# How to find who changed SSAS database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas

I have a production SSAS 2008 database, and 2 of the cubes sometimes disappear.  I am assuming they are deleted by a human, but I cant find where this action could be logged.  Does anyone know whether SSAS logs actions such as deleting cubes, and where those logs would be ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

oh !

Possibly, keep the profiler running against the SSAS ? If I would guess, it may be automated clean-up process or somebody thinking your production server is a "Test" server !

When it is deleted, there is likely to be Object Deleted event. You may filter for this event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/object-deleted-event-class

[image]